# How to resume or restart paused conversation in RASA

Tags: python, rasa

In my chatbot I paused conversation by returning `ConversationPaused()` to pause conversation so that real agent can handle. But how can I resume that paused conversation ?

This is what I have done

```
from rasa_core.events import ConversationPaused
class ActionTalkToAgent(Action):
    def name(self):
        return "action_talk_to_agent"
    def run(self, dispatcher, tracker, domain):
        if tracker.get_slot("lang") == "bn":
            dispatcher.utter_template("utter_restart_bot_bn", tracker)
        else:
            dispatcher.utter_template("utter_restart_bot_en", tracker)
        return [ConversationPaused()]
```

Comment: please share your code

Comment: @FabioSpaghetti , I have updated my question.

Comment: I have the same problem, I cant resume it

Answer (score 0):

Use the below class and include the below action in bot’s domain file.

```
class ActionRestarted(Action):
""" This is for restarting the chat"""

def name(self):
    return "action_chat_restart"

def run(self, dispatcher, tracker, domain):
    return [Restarted()]
```